# Suppose f is nonnegative and continuous on [1,2] and that $\int_{1}^{2}x^kf(x)dx=5+k^2$ for $k=0,1,2$ prove:

Tags: real-analysis

a) $\int_{1}^{4}f(\sqrt{x})dx=12$

b) $\int_{\sqrt{2}/2}^{1}f(1/x^2)dx\geq 5/2$

c) $\int_{0}^{1}x^2f(x+1)dx=2$

Any direction will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try $u$-substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) and (b) can be done by appropriate substitutions. For (c),we use the three integrals with $k=0,1,2$ to get
\begin{align*}
\int_1^2(x-1)^2 \, f(x) \, dx &=\int_1^2x^2 \, f(x) \, dx-\int_1^22x \, f(x) \, dx+\int_1^21 \, f(x) \, dx\\& = (5+2^2)-2(5+1^2)+(5+0^2)\\
&=2.
\end{align*}
Now use the substitution, $x-1=t$, to get the answer for (c).

Comment: Why can we divide the integral as such?

Comment: @KennyE because the integral operator is linear, in the sense $\int f+g \, dx =\int f \,dx +\int g\, dx$.